# How to count the occurrences of an observation from 0 and store it in a new variable in R?

Tags: r, database, variables, dplyr, tidyverse

I have some hotel guest data that looks like this:

| guest_id | stay_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 1 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 3 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 3 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 3 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 8 | YYYY-MM-DD |
| 8 | YYYY-MM-DD |

I want to create an additional counter variable that counts the previous stays of the guest (by guest_id) at the hotel where the counter increments from 0 and counts each stay beyond that. The output should look like this:

| guest_id | stay_date | previous_stay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YYYY-MM-DD | 0 |
| 1 | YYYY-MM-DD | 1 |
| 4 | YYYY-MM-DD | 0 |
| 4 | YYYY-MM-DD | 1 |
| 4 | YYYY-MM-DD | 2 |
| 8 | YYYY-MM-DD | 0 |
| 8 | YYYY-MM-DD | 1 |
| 4 | YYYY-MM-DD | 3 |

These are the codes I've tried so far (they produce the same result) and they do a pretty good job but the problem is they do not start from 0, they start incrementing from 1.

```r
stayData <- read_csv("guestStays.csv") %>%
  group_by(guest_id) %>%
  mutate(previous_stay = row_number())
 
stayData <-
  read_csv("guestsStays.csv") %>%  
  group_by(guest_id) %>%
  mutate(previous_stay = 1:n())
```

If anyone knows a command to do this using the dplyr package in R that would awesome. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `row_number() - 1L`?

Comment: That did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

r2evans solved it. The answer is:

```
stayData <- read_csv("guestStays.csv") %>%
  group_by(guest_id) %>%
  mutate(previous_stay = row_number()- 1L)
```

Comment: fyi, code blocks look much better when *surrounded* by code fences (`\`\`\`` on its own line), due to embedded newlines and a fixed-with font); see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. For example, see my suggested edit for the original question.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that in the future.